# Joining two `List` objects into one of abstract data type

Tags: c#

Suppose there's the following set up (assume equal lengths and general niceness of the data).

```
List<String> 
  a = GetStrings(0), 
  b = GetStrings(1);
for(int i = 0; i < a.Count; i++)
  yield return new SuperString{ A = a[i], B = b[i] };
```

What I wonder is if this can be refactored into a `foreach` loop and if it'd look very ugly then. I prefer using it before `for` since the operation will be performed on **each** of the element pair.

EDIT:

I might have been to scarce on the details. Sorry about that. What if the types are arbitrary? I.e. as the following?

```
IEnumerable<Cool> a = GetCool();
IEnumerable<Lame> b = GetLame();

for(int i = 0; i < a.Count; i++)
  yield return new Opposites{ A = a[i], B = b[i] };
```

Comment: OK... My first though: "hit the report flag on this jack-donkey!"... Then I checked and **there actually IS** a `Zip` method... Never heard of it!

Comment: @Chamster: Comment flags should not be used for technically incorrect comments.

Comment: ?! I thought they were **precisely** for that. If a comment is of a very low quality or plain spam, I always try to report it... Am I wrong, I'll be happy to adapt an other way of conduct. Please advise.

Answer (score 10):

How about no loop at all?

```
a.Zip(b, (aa, bb) => new SuperString{A = aa, B = bb})
```

the benefit of the `Zip` method is that it will stop at the end of the shorter of the two sequences in the case they're of differing lengths.

Note: if you're using .net < 4, you'll want to take @Cuong's method.

In the case that your types are arbitrary, exactly the same should work:

```
IEnumerable<Cool> a = GetCool();
IEnumerable<Lame> b = GetLame();
a.Zip(b, (aa, bb) => new Opposites{A = aa, B = bb});
```

with the caveat that property `A` of `Opposites` must be of type `Cool` and `B` of type `Lame` (or a parent type)

Comment: you should change (a, b) to (x, y) because they are the same name with the list

Comment: Ah, I was fighting and whining because I didn't get it to work. VS nagged about conflicts in the scope but I was too stuck on the new (and VERY cool `Zip` thingy)...

Comment: @spender I'm having troubles getting it to work on my ** REAL** example. I've edited the original question. Please have a look. As far intellisense tells me, I only have `Zip` with 3 arguments, not 2. Am I missing something?

Comment: Oh, I just realized where the third argument's coming from. It's the `this` part that I missed. The first argument is in fact the object itself, du'h... I got so excited for this `Zip`-er, I forgot to think, haha! Now it's working great. Splendid support, guys!

Answer (score 5):

Beside `Zip`, you could use `Enumerable.Range`:

```
Enumerable.Range(0, a.Count)
          .Select(i => new SuperString{ A = a[i], B = b[i] });
```

Comment: @spender: +1 for your mention :)

Comment: @spender Note that it's fairly simple to define your own `Zip` method in 3.5.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Zip method:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx))

```
var result = Enumerable.Zip(
    GetStrings(0), 
    GetStrings(1), 
    (x,y) => new SuperString{ x,y}
);
```

Also, don't miss this part of the documentation :

> If the sequences do not have the same number of elements, the method merges sequences until it reaches the end of one of them. For example, if one sequence has three elements and the other one has four, the result sequence will have only three elements.